# How can i show native ads in ListView android?

Tags: android, listview, native-ads

I need to show native ads in List-view, i search and getting the result which is not in List-view all results related to recycle view or Card-view.

I also try clock-byte code but its not working also its deprecated.

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far